# How to multiply and sum values in a flat table with grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, cumsum, factors

I have got the following dataframe:

```
lst=[['2021','2021-11-01','A','AA',1.02],['2021','2021-11-01','B','BB',1.1],['2021','2021-12-01','A','AA',1.3],['2021','2021-12-01','B','BB',1.25],['2022','2022-01-01','A','AA',1.25],['2022','2022-01-01','B','BB',1.4]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['YEAR','Month','P1','P2','factor'])
```

I would like to multiply the column factor month, P1 and P2 for each year. Below is what I would like to get.

```
lst=[['2021','2021-11-01','A','AA',1.02,1.02],['2021','2021-11-01','B','BB',1.1,1.1],['2021','2021-12-01','A','AA',1.3,1.326],['2021','2021-12-01','B','BB',1.25,1.375],['2022','2022-01-01','A','AA',1.25,1.25],['2022','2022-01-01','B','BB',1.4,1.4]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['YEAR','Month','P1','P2','factor','cumfactor'])
```

I tried the function groupby with cumprod, but it did not work

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `['YEAR', 'P1', 'P2']` and [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumprod.html):

```
df2['cumfactor'] = df2.groupby(['YEAR', 'P1', 'P2'])['factor'].cumprod()
```

*NB. ensure first that the dataframe is sorted by YEAR/Month: `df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'Month'])`*

output:

```
   YEAR       Month P1  P2  factor  cumfactor
0  2021  2021-11-01  A  AA    1.02      1.020
1  2021  2021-11-01  B  BB    1.10      1.100
2  2021  2021-12-01  A  AA    1.30      1.326
3  2021  2021-12-01  B  BB    1.25      1.375
4  2022  2022-01-01  A  AA    1.25      1.250
5  2022  2022-01-01  B  BB    1.40      1.400
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumprod.html) by columns `['YEAR', 'P1', 'P2']` and processing column `factor`:

```
#if necessary sorting per datetime column
#df2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Month'])
#df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'Month'], ignore_index=True)

df2['cumfactor'] = df2.groupby(['YEAR', 'P1', 'P2'])['factor'].cumprod()
print (df2)  
   YEAR       Month P1  P2  factor  cumfactor
0  2021  2021-11-01  A  AA    1.02      1.020
1  2021  2021-11-01  B  BB    1.10      1.100
2  2021  2021-12-01  A  AA    1.30      1.326
3  2021  2021-12-01  B  BB    1.25      1.375
4  2022  2022-01-01  A  AA    1.25      1.250
5  2022  2022-01-01  B  BB    1.40      1.400
```